# How to install m2e-wtp using headless p2

Tags: eclipse, p2

I have this problem I've been struggling with for a while. I want to install Eclipse plugins automatically during an automated Eclipse installation process. So far I've been able to install the following over fresh eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz:

```
./eclipse -nosplash \
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
  -repository http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e4.2/ \
  -installIU org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group \
  -installIU org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group \
  -installIU org.codehaus.groovy17.feature.feature.group \
  -installIU org.codehaus.groovy18.feature.feature.group \
  -installIU org.codehaus.groovy20.feature.feature.group \
  -repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases \
  -installIU org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group \
  -repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201207090125/ \
  -installIU org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.feature.feature.group \
  -repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-buildhelper/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201207090124 \
  -installIU org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group \
  -repository http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-extensions/m2e-apt \
  -installIU org.jboss.tools.maven.apt.feature.feature.group \
  -repository http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-extensions/m2e-jdt-compiler/ \
  -installIU org.jboss.tools.m2e.jdt.feature.feature.group
```

All is nice but when I try to import a Groovy, Maven-managed web application project Eclipse starts complaining about missing m2e-wtp being missing. Now here's the real issue. I can install it either using UI (which is what I don't want) and then it works but tries to install both org.jboss.tools.maven.apt.feature.feature.group and org.jboss.tools.m2e.jdt.feature.feature.group once again and then the missing org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group.
When I install it using P2 as follows

```
./eclipse -nosplash \
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
  -repository http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/ \
  -installIU org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group \
```

nothing works anymore even Eclipse does not find anything on the Eclipse Market.

Can someone shed some light on how to install those dependencies properly?

An example project can be found on Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/padcom/groovy-spring-web-example

Comment: You can also shorten it by listing the repositories and IUs as comma separated (with no whitespace) values.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was. I have forgotten to add the

```
org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse.feature.group
```

feature while installing Groovy Eclipse thus there was noting to connect Eclipse and Maven.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: This seems to solve your problem, so you should accept your own answer. This allows people to see that this questiond doesn't require further answers directly in the search results view.